# Database design for document management?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

We are providing document upload on different things like tasks, feeds, comments etc..
And there are lots different permission on documents for which user can share it or download it. Document is private or public.

We already have legacy code and database but it's not maintainable and scalable.

I want to get idea how should I have to design a database which covers all this scenarios. And it will be maintainable and scalable for other users.

Any example or solution  ?

Comment: Given your almost non-existent specification, this question is too general to answer. Sounds like you need to learn about database/application design generally.

Comment: @Raoul I want to get the idea how it should be if someone has already designed something like this.

Comment: Your description of your application is too vague to be able to give you an example schema. It would be quicker to examine your application requirements and create your own. Sound like you just want a working solution to copy. This won't happen since your question is too vague

Comment: is there some reason why you don't use a Content Management system for this? Why do you want to build your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "upload on tasks, feeds, comments, etc."  It would be useful if you could provide more detail or even the legacy database structure.  Here's a general idea, though...

```
--users--
uid
name
email
(etc)

--comments--
cid
uid
docid
date
text

--documents--
docid
uid
upload_date
(etc)

--permissions--
pid
docid
uid
```

The "comments" table would be for comments on the document (if that's what you were looking for?).
The "permissions" table is just a list of document ids and user ids who are allowed to access the document.  Or, you could even define permissions via groups of users (which would require another table, but you get the idea).